# XML size limit for XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

Is there any limit for XML size for which XSLT is applied by `XslCompiledTransform` in .NET (3.5)? Also, is there any limitation for a length of parameters passed to XSLT?

**UPDATE:** I did not mean the amount of parameters, but the length of a string, which is passed as a parameter and length of an XML text, to which XSLT is applied.

Comment: It's useful, when you have a question like this, to simply write a test for it and see what happens.  It's not at all difficult to write a program that creates a 2gb string and passes it to an XSLT transform as a parameter, and in so doing you'll learn something that you can't learn any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any limit for XML size for
>   which XSLT is applied by
>   XslCompiledTransform in .NET (3.5)?
>   Also, is there any limitation for a
>   length of parameteres passed to XSLT?

**No**.

**The memory consumption is usually overwhelmed by the size of the XML document**. A somewhat course rule I have heard of is to multiply the size of the XML document by 5 and this would give you the approximate amount of RAM that might be necessary to hold that document in RAM.

So, a 2GB XML document has good chances of being processed on a 12GB RAM 64-bit machine.

**Note, that there is no guarantee how long such processing may take** -- just that it would be possible to hold such a document in memory.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there aren't any hard limits on the amount of XML or the length of string parameters that can be processed by the [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) class.

However, applying an XSL transformation might potentially increase the memory consumption of your application considerably, depending on the amount of XML data being processed.

In some cases it may even go beyond the 2 GB limit imposed to 32-bit processes. If this situation should occur, the application might have to be compiled and run in 64-bit.

Comment: Possibly, I wasn't clear enough when asking. I have ment not the amount of parameters, but the length of a string, which is passed as a parameter and length of an XML text, to which XSLT is applied.

Comment: I am not aware of any hard limits imposed on the length of string parameters either. I updated my answer.